# Increase body limit for specific route with ExpressJS

Tags: node.js, express

We have a REST API built with ExpressJS. One of our routes is getting files as binary data in the JSON request body. Therefore we want to increase the limit of the body.

Simple version of our starting index.js file

```
const start = async () => {
    try {
        // Connect to database
        await connectDB(process.env.DATABASE_URL);

        // Create app
        const app = express();

        // Body parser
        app.use(express.json()); //100kb default
        app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

        // Mount routes
        app.use(`/${process.env.API_VERSION}`, authRoutes);
        app.use(`/${process.env.API_VERSION}`, profileRoutes);
        app.use(`/${process.env.API_VERSION}`, filesRoutes);
        app.use(`/${process.env.API_VERSION}`, ticketRoutes);

        // Error handler
        app.use(errorHandler);

        // Not found handler
        app.use(notFoundHandler);

        // Start server
        const server = app.listen(process.env.PORT, () => {
            console.log(`Server running in ${process.env.NODE_ENV} mode on http://${process.env.HOST}:${process.env.PORT}/${process.env.API_VERSION}`)
        });

    } catch(error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
}

start();
```

At this point the limit for all routes is 100kb.

Inside our `filesRoutes` we have 1 specific upload route where we want to increase this limit to 200mb.

```
import express from 'express';
import { uploadFiles, getFiles, downloadFile, deleteFile } from '../controllers/filesController.js';
import authorize from '../middleware/authorizeHandler.js';

const router = express.Router();

router.get('files', authorize, getFiles);
router.get('files/:id/download', authorize, downloadFile);
router.post('files/upload', [authorize, express.json({ limit: '200mb' })], uploadFile);
router.delete('files/:id', authorize, deleteFile);

export default router;
```

I added `express.json({ limit: '200mb' })` to the upload route but I'm getting an error back `request entity too large`.

Comment: That's because you have this in the `index.js` file: `app.use(express.json());`. This is applied for all routes

Comment: You can [pass a path](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#path-examples) in `app.use` and it also accepts regex. You can add a regex which accepts all paths, except for your  `uploadBinary` path in the `index.js` file.

Comment: better an performant way would be using file streams to upload the large file and pipe the request to get data in chunks

Comment: @vighnesh153 I was hoping we could overwrite the middleware for a specific route. We will check to write a regex. Thanks!

Comment: @BrijeshDave: That's not an option. The client wants to sent the binary content as json in one request

Answer (score 3):

Based on @vighnesh153 comment we could fix the issue by changing `app.use(express.json());` to `app.use(/^(?!\/api\/files\/upload$)/, express.json());` and add `express.json({ limit: '200mb' })` as middleware to the `api/files/upload` route

Comment: This seems like the correct solution - this should probably be in the official documentation for `express.json()`

Comment: Asked whether it could be documented here: https://github.com/expressjs/express/issues/5197